# WSO2 ESB - Adding databases through Admin Console Feature

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2 ESB and then I've started by following the initial steps described on WSO2 ESB product documentaion page. After the first samples succesfully run, I've got myself stuck trying to exercise the Database mechanism.

According to WSO2 ESB documentation - http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Databases - Admin Console feature must be installed to add a new database. So, I've tried to add that feature to my  ESB installation by creating several repositories (http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/3.0.0 up to 4.0.5 and even the local version of 4.0.5 p2-repo.zip) , but after all I had no success in finding the Admin Console Feature, so no Database option for me. Even after adding the Datasources Feature, the Database option did not show up.

What am I missing here ? Is the documentation outdated ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otmar, That particular database provisioning feature that you are referring to as admin console feature was renamed to "rss manager". Please lookup for the feature with that name in the p2 feature repository.

Comment: Thanks Prabath, I found that feature ! When the docs get outdated, what is my best guess to look for most recent version of a feature ?

Comment: That;s indeed one option. In addition to that you can always refer the public release note that we send out after every release in our public mailing lists architecture@wso2.org or dev@wso2.org

Comment: Good to know that, Prabath. I've subscribed to both of them, thanks for the directions.